# using p12 container in boost::asio server

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I need to make server using boost::asio works on SSL.
I have seen the boost examples but didn't find it useful as I have p12 container. Can any body help me out to establish secure connection using p12 container in boost::asio?

How do I use p12 container in below code snippet(from boost [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp))?

```
    context_.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    context_.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&server::get_password, this));
    context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
    context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh512.pem");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All the functions are documented. Start with [PKCS12_create](ftp://ftp.ulakbim.gov.tr/pub/openssl/docs/crypto/PKCS12_create.html) and [PKCS12_parse](ftp://ftp.ulakbim.gov.tr/pub/openssl/docs/crypto/PKCS12_parse.html). If you get lost, there's [example code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL096/OpenSSL096-15/openssl/apps/pkcs12.c) right in the OpenSSL distribution.

Comment: Hi David, noted that PKCS12_parse can help me in this case. But I want to parse p12 container using boost::asio.
Do you have any suggestion for the same?

Comment: You have a screwdriver and a hammer. You need to put in a screw. Why would you even think of doing it with the hammer? Put the screw in with the screwdriver, and then use the hammer on the nails. (In other words, use OpenSSL to parse the PKCS#12 file. Then use `boost::asio::ssl` to wrap OpenSSL as you do IO. That's what the two tools are for and why they are used together.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved it through combination of openSSL library and boost library. As I didnot found anything helpful in boost for P12 container.

Using openSSL library decrypted P12 container and then used boost to communicate.